# Adding data to a socket.io socket object

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to add some custom information to my socket object on connect, so that when I disconnect the socket, I can read that custom information.

**IE:**

```
// (Client)
socket.on('connect', function(data){
  socket.customInfo = 'customdata';
});

// (server)
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log(socket.customInfo);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is JavaScript you can freely add attributes to any object (just as you did). However socket.io does give you a built-in way to do that (so you won't have to worry about naming conflicts):

```
socket.set('nickname', name, function () {
  socket.emit('ready');
});

socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
  console.log('Chat message by ', name);
});
```

Note that this is only on one side (either client or server). Obviously you can't share data between client and server without communication (that's what your example suggests).

The **socket** in your browser and the **socket** in the server won't share the same properties if you set them.
Basically you have set the data only at the client side (which is in your browsers memory NOT on the server).

Comment: Apparently not. I'm using socket.io 1.3.4

Comment: 2021 update: [Use `socket.data`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128624/114558).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for an answer, there are a couple of things you can do to share data from the client to the server without actually sending a message.

1. Add a custom property to the `auth` property in the client socketIo options. This will be available to the server event handlers in `socket.handshake.auth.xxxx`.
2. Add a custom header to the `transportOptions.polling.extraHeaders` property in the client socketIo options. This will ONLY be presented when the socket.io client is connected via polling and not when "upgraded" to websockets (as you can't have custom headers then).
3. Add a custom query property to the client socketIo options. I don't recommend this since it potentially exposes the data to intermediate proxies.