# Binding attribute to socket object from server side doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So in the server Im trying to bind some attributes to the socket object which I can read from my client but this is only working for the first attribute.

Heres what I run

```
socket.isPlayer = true;
socket.isWaiting = true;
socket.playerNum = 0;
```

but on the client all I see  is the `socket.isPlayer` attribute. Any ideas whats going on, help much appreciated.

Heres my full server side file

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    PlayingGame = mongoose.model('PlayingGame'),
    FinishedGame = mongoose.model('FinishedGame');

var waitingGame = null;
/*we use this variable to refrence the socket of the waiting player
so when we start a game we can set the isWaiting attribute to false
prevent joining a game with yourself*/
var waitingSocket = null;


/* HELPERS */
var emitError = function(socket, err) {
    socket.emit(err);
};

var getSocketGameId = function(socket) {
    for (var room in socket.rooms) {
        if (room.substring(0, 4) === 'game') {
            return room.substring(5);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/* helpers */


var createNewGame = function(socket, username) {
    var newGame = {};
    newGame.player1 = username;
    var playingGame = new PlayingGame(newGame);
    socket.join('game:' + playingGame.id);
    waitingGame = playingGame;
    console.log('new game room id', waitingGame.id);

    socket.isPlayer = true;
    socket.isWaiting = true;
    socket.playerNum = 0;
    console.log('socket', socket.playerNum);
    waitingSocket = socket;
};

var startNewGame = function(socket, username, io) {
    socket.isPlayer = true;
    socket.playerNum = 1;
    console.log('starting new game');
    waitingGame.player2 = username;
    waitingGame.save(function(err) {
        if (err) emitError('Failed to save game');
        else {
            socket.join('game:' + waitingGame.id);
            io.to('game:' + waitingGame.id).emit('start new game', waitingGame);
        }
        waitingGame = null;
        waitingSocket.isWaiting = false;
        waitingSocket = null;
    });
};

var closeGame = function(socket, io) {
    console.log('closing game');
    // Check if game is still playing if no, assume its already been closed, do nothing
    var gameId = getSocketGameId(socket);
    if (gameId === null) return;

    console.log('finding ', gameId);
    PlayingGame.findById(gameId, function(err, game) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw 'Problem finding game when closing';
        }

        console.log(game);
        // if game found, move PlayingGame to FinishedGame emit game closed to room
        if (game) {
            console.log('Saving game to finished games');
            var finishedGame = new FinishedGame(game.toObject());
            finishedGame.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw 'Problem saving finished game when moving playing game to finished game';
                console.log('Successfuly saved to finish game');
                game.remove(function(err) {
                    if (err) throw 'Problem removing from playing games';

                    socket.leave('game:' + gameId);
                    // send message to room that the game has been closed
                    io.to('game:' + gameId).emit('game closed');
                });
            });
        }

    });
};

var startSpectating = function(socket, gameId) {
    // Send game info
    var gameInfo;
    var found = false;
    PlayingGame.findById(gameId, function(err, game) {
        if (err) socket.emit('game not found');
        else {
            gameInfo = game;
            socket.emit('gameInfo')

            // Join game room
            socket.join('game:' + gameId);

            socket.isPlayer = false;
        }
    });
};

module.exports = function(io, socket) {
    socket.on('join game', function(data) {
        console.log('New game request', data);
        if (waitingGame == null) createNewGame(socket, data.username);
        else startNewGame(socket, data.username, io);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('socket disconnected');
        if (socket.isPlayer) closeGame(socket, io);
    });

    socket.on('leaving game', function() {
        console.log('leaving game');
        if (socket.isPlayer) {
            if (socket.isWaiting) {
                waitingGame = null;
                waitingSocket = null;
            } else {
                closeGame(socket, io);
            }
        } else {
            // the socket is a spectator all we need to do is remove from room
            for (var room in socket.rooms) {
                if (room.substring(0, 4) === 'game') {
                    socket.leave(room);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('spectate', function(data) {
        startSpectating(socket, data.gameId);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why would you expect properties added to the server-side socket object to magically appear on the client-side socket object?

Comment: How come it works sometimes then? I saw this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351881/adding-data-to-a-socket-io-socket-object

Comment: The answer in that link mentions using `socket.get()`/`socket.set()`, which I've never really seen before. Your code doesn't use those methods however.

Comment: he says those are just for convenience so you don't override any other attributes which Im positive im not doing anyways

Comment: Right, but the properties being attached are not automagically visible on the other side, they're only visible on the same end. You might be able to create a special object on both ends that uses ES6 proxies to automagically do this, but IMHO it's both a bad idea and it requires ES6 support on the front end which may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you cannot do this". Long one below.

`socket` is an object on **the server side** of your application. Currently I'm not aware of automagical way to share properties between the server and the client. The reason for that is that it's a simple socket connection and all the data that should be shared **must travel** to the client somehow. So simply setting properties means sending actual packages to the client.

But this is extremely inefficient because this means that you **cannot store** any kind of properties on the server side **without sending** them to the client. And most of the time you do need such an "option".

Furthermore simply setting properties does nothing in pure JavaScript - you must have the so called magic functions, getters/setters, any kind of "new" type of JS functionality. What I mean is that there's no built-in way to determine if you've set something or not, which is the second big no-no in your situation.

p.s.
If you read carefully the topic you've shared, it's simply stated `Note that this is only on one side (either client or server)`. It's just a method for setting properties in order to be sure you don't override any of the methods (`emit` for example).

Comment: Hmm I'm still wondering though how come the isPlayer property is visible on client?

Comment: If it's property was false, then there you go :D

Comment: No the property is sometimes true, it works as it should

Comment: It is most definitely **something else**!

Comment: I wonder if this is possible now with https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/#Socket-data

Comment: From what I can see, this is only backend feature.